# PHP code included in HTML won't update

Tags: php, html, include

I currently have a PHP file which will search my MySQL database and see if a user is logged in. If they are logged in, it will echo "Welcome 'username'. Logout" and if they're not logged in it will echo "Login. Register."

If I view this PHP file directly, it will echo out the correct text, depending on whether or not I am logged in. However, if I put into my HTML file using include it will only echo out the logged out text, regardless of whether I'm logged in.

Is there some conflict between PHP and HTML which will stop it from printing out the correct text maybe? It seems strange that it will work opening the PHP file itself, but not when it's included in HTML.

HTML code:

```
<?php include "loginreg/check.php"; ?>
```

Would the fact it's in a subfolder make a difference? Haven't included the PHP code as that itself is working, but I have got it if you need to see it.

Cheers

PHP code:

```
// Gets IP address
$ip = visitorIP();

// Connect to database
mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die('Unable to select database');

$query  = "SELECT * FROM loggedin WHERE userip='$ip'";
$result = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
if ($result == '0') {
    mysql_close();
    loggedOut();
    return;
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['sid'])) {
    $sessionid = $_COOKIE['sid'];
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['sessionid'] == $sessionid) {
        mysql_close();
        loggedIn($row['id']);
    } else {
        mysql_close();
        loggedOut();
    }
}

function visitorIP() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $TheIp = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $TheIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return trim($TheIp);
}

function loggedIn($id) {
    global $username, $password, $database;
    mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die('Unable to select database');

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $fname = $row['fname'];
        $sname = $row['sname'];
    }

    echo "<div class=\"fltrt\">Welcome, " . $fname . ". <a href=\"http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/loginreg/logout.php\">Logout</a></div>";
}

function loggedOut() {
    echo "<div class=\"fltrt\"><a href=\"http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/loginreg/login.html\">Login</a> <a href=\"http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/loginreg/register.html\">Register</a></div>";
}
```

Comment: Show the contents of `loginreg/check.php`.

Comment: My first thought is a path issue.

Comment: are you using sessions to check the login status, you have to start session before any html start [link]http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: @ArunKumar no I'm not, when the user logs in I get their IP address and generate a random sessionID which are stored in the database. Then a cookie is placed on the user's system storing the sessionID. When I check, I get the user's IP address, look it up from database, get the matching sessionID from the database and check that with the cookie stored on their system

Comment: @Matt thanks Matt, I'll have a look through that - didn't realise they were being deprecated, only started looking at PHP a couple of weeks ago!

Comment: @arxanas I've put the code up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting cookies while inside a subdirectory. Use the `path` parameter of `setcookie` to ensure you're setting the cookie in the root folder of your website:

```
// Sets the cookie for the root of the domain:
setcookie("username", "foo", time() + 60 * 60, "/");
```

Comment: Ahh lifesaver! I found example code online for the `setcookie()` bit which didn't include the `path` parameter so just assumed that it only took the 2 parameters! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code of both scripts this is just a guess, but a likely problem would be that you are outputting html (anything...) before you include your `loginreg/check.php` script.

That would render any `session_start()` statements in your included file useless as the headers already have been sent. And not being able to get to the session would lead to the error that you describe.

**Edit:** For cookies the same principle applies, they need to be set before the headers are sent so before you output anything to the browser.

Comment: I'm not using any `session_start()` statements at all. I am outputting HTML before the include statement - if I were to put this right at the start of the HTML file, how would I then go about getting the output of the PHP and putting it in the right place within the HTML file?

Comment: @Crazyloonybin Just put the output in a string instead of echoing it out and then in your html file echo that string where you want it.

Comment: would I put the `include` within the `<head>` tags or just before? And if I were to return the string instead of echoing, how would I then access that string within the `<body>`?

Comment: @Crazyloonybin Before **any** output (including spaces, new-lines, etc.) so before the `<head>`. You don't need to return anything when you include a file, just assign it to a variable and that variable will be available in your html file after your include.

Comment: When you say assign to a variable, do you mean within the PHP bit? For example, `<?php $var = include('loginreg/check.php'); ?>` and then where I want to output it, `<?php echo $var; ?>`? Sorry if I'm being stupid here!

Comment: @Crazyloonybin No, just return a string from your functions and assign that string to a variable. All inside your `loginreg/check.php` script.

Comment: Ahh ok I see what you mean, I can see how that works now!Just tried arxanas' solution below and that does actually work, but thanks for the help anyway! I've learnt something new from you at least! :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but are you trying to use a PHP include in an HTML file?  If so, that will never work (unless you've got some custom server config that will parse PHP code in HTML files).

PHP code is for PHP files.  HTML code can work in HTML and PHP files.  You cannot do a PHP include, in an HTML file.

Comment: Yes, I modified the .htaccess file to parse the PHP inside HTML files as I didn't want to be writing all my HTML as echo statements within a PHP file.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case what you did is perfectly valid.  =)